# Blazor JS scripts into a blazor component

Tags: javascript, blazor

I am building a Blazor app, I need to  dynamically add a JavaScript file that is used only in a single Blazor component. As you would be aware Blazor allows adding script tags only to the root HTML document. This makes it difficult to add JavaScript files that are required only in a single component.

The script is

It is important to set the data-main="payment-js" attribute on the script tag.

Are there any restrictions around iframe rendering in Blazor?  The script renders multiple iframes on the specific Blazor components as part a PCI compliant payment system integration.

The script works in a simple HTML file.

I would be grateful for any assistance

Comment: The script is
<script data-main="payment-js" src="https://gateway.tillpayments.com/js/integrated/payment.1.3.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:**

Maybe `MarkupString` could help:

```
@((MarkupString)script)

@code {
    string script = "<script data-main="payment-js" src="gateway.tillpayments.com/js/integrated/…>";
}
```

**Old answer:**

You could use the special `HeadContent` component to add the script in the `<head>` tag from your component.

```
<HeadContent>
    <script suppress-error="BL9992" data-main="payment-js" src="gateway.tillpayments.com/js/integrated/…>
</HeadContent>
```

You have to add attribute `suppress-error="BL9992"` so that it won't give you Error RZ9992.

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/control-head-content?view=aspnetcore-6.0#control-head-content-in-a-razor-component

Also there is this library for loading scripts in blazor: https://github.com/excubo-ag/Blazor.ScriptInjection

Comment: I added 
<HeadContent><script data-main="payment-js" src="https://gateway.tillpayments.com/js/integrated/payment.1.3.min.js"></script> </HeadContent> 
to my Blazor component – 
 
Now I am getting

Error RZ9992 Script tags should not be placed inside components because they cannot be updated dynamically. To fix this, move the script tag to the 'index.html' file or another static location.

Comment: @datateam Hi, I updated my answer with another possible solution. You can try to add `suppress-error="BL9992"` attribute or use `MarkupString` approach.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by using a `script loader` and `JSRuntime`. Check [this](https://www.geekinsta.com/add-javascript-in-blazor-components/) out.

Answer (score 1):

try JavaScript isolation in JavaScript modules:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#javascript-isolation-in-javascript-modules&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5005078

download payment.1.3.min.js to your wwwroot, and try this codes

```
public partial class Demos : IAsyncDisposable
{

    [Inject] IJSRuntime? JS { get; set; }
    private IJSObjectReference? module;



    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        try
        {
            if (firstRender)
            {
                module = await JS!.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./payment.1.3.min.js" + "?v=" + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version);
                Instance = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
             }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (OnError != null) await OnError.Invoke(e.Message);
        }
    }

    public virtual async Task DoSomePayment(string fileName, string fileURL)
    {
        await module!.InvokeVoidAsync("payment1234", fileName, fileURL);
    }

    async ValueTask IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (module is not null)
        {
            await module.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }
}
```