# Blazor jsinterop issue. Using <script> tags in imported js file fails

Tags: javascript, blazor

In my Blazor app, I'm dynamically importing javascript files as I need them, which works fine for vanilla javascript files.

Now, in one of those javascript files, I'd like to add features by having it reference another third-party javascript library, such as by using the < script > tags, but that doesn't work.

```
<script src="thirdParty.js">   </script>

export async function MainFunction() {
 {some logic that calls into thirdParty.js}
}
```

I also tried combining the two JS files, but the third-party library didn't like that, though this is probably the normal answer.

How do I have one JS file utilize another JS file in Blazor?

Comment: Are you adding a `<script>`  tag inside a .js file? That does not work in JavaScript generally, it's not something specific to Blazor

Comment: @dimlucas, I am adding it to the js file, yes, but I didn't expect it to work.  Not sure how to approach the problem I'm trying to solve though.  How do I have one JS file utilize another JS file in Blazor?

Comment: Can you share some code of what you tried?

Comment: Check if that third party library can be imported as an es6 module e.g. `import { export1 } from "module-name";`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @DimitrisMaragkos.  Didn't work out though, there's no exported features

Comment: Then I believe the best option is to import the traditional way, by adding the script tag inside `index.html` (or `_Layout.cshtml` if you use server-side blazor). Also check this answer might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73179765/blazor-js-scripts-into-a-blazor-component/73179875#73179875

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos.  I don't have a problem importing the first JS file.  The problem is I need the first JS file to use functions in the second JS file, and I don't know how to do that.  I will check your link out, thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247632/discussion-between-dimitris-maragkos-and-sean).